# postgres: use of CASE and ANY() in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there some way to make this work?

```
SELECT
*
FROM table t
INNER JOIN othertable t2 USING (tid)
WHERE
t.tid =
CASE
    WHEN t2.someboolval THEN ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16])
    ELSE ANY(ARRAY[77,66])
END
```

Unfortunately I can't just do `t.tid = CASE WHEN t2.someboolval THEN 1 ELSE 2 END` because I need to match against an array. Is this doable?

Answer (score 13):

Use AND/OR. Something like:

```
  SELECT
  *
  FROM table t
  INNER JOIN othertable t2 USING (tid)
  WHERE
     t2.someboolval AND t.tid IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16) 
     OR NOT (t2.someboolval) and t.id IN (77,66)
```

Edit: formatted

Answer (score 6):

You have to change place of ANY:

```
SELECT
*
FROM table t
INNER JOIN othertable t2 USING (tid)
WHERE
  t.tid =
  ANY(CASE
    WHEN t2.someboolval THEN ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
    ELSE ARRAY[77,66]
  END)
```